# Is debug apk size is greater than same apk in google play store

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is debug apk size is greater than same apk in google play store
My apk size is 8mb can this apk's size will reduced when i upload to play store

Answer (score 0):

APK size depends on a lot of factors. 
You can use App Bundles to upload on playstore to reduce the size of the APK downloaded to each type of device since the APKs served from Play Store to the devices consists of resources only required for those device configuration.

You can further reduce size by using Minification and Resource shrinking. Also make sure to convert all the images to WebP(Check compatibility for minimum SDK version you support before doing it) which can reduce the size 30-50% more(only for images).

Watch this video to know more on the topic: [Google I/O 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0raqVydJmNE)

Comment: Or convert to SVG.

Comment: Yes but most of the images are not easily convertible to SVGs, also you have to make sure SVGs work on all the devices properly. I have had quite a few cases where for some reason SVGs doesn't on XIAOMI devices

Comment: Agree with you. Xiaomi is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

Google play store apk size is lesser if you are uploading a Android App Bundle format. see more info about Android App Bundle here - https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#aab_format

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't opt for `App Bundle` , the APK size does reduce to some extent. But only, say, ~ 5 - 10%

`App Bundle` is the best way to reduce the app size